# How do I remove a graphic in a Java Program implemented with JPanel?

Tags: java, path-finding

So currently I am running an rudimentary implementation of the A* pathfinding algorithm, using the distance to the goal node as the heuristic. As part of the interface, I am utilizing a clock and text where the program tells the user when the algorithm is trying to find the shortest path ("denoted as ***solving*** ) and when the algorithm has successfully found the shortest path.

The following screenshot shows an instance of the shortest path. I want to be able to get rid of the solving screen after the clock finishes so I can print **"Solved ㋡"** on the graphics screen. How do I remove and replace the text in this graphic using a JPanel method ?

[image]

```
g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 60)); 
            g.drawString("Solving...", map.length * 60 / 2, map.length * 60 / 2 );
            g.setColor(new Color(148, 0, 211));
            g.fillRect(minx*60, miny  * 60, 60, 60);
            startx = minx;
            starty = miny;
            marked[startx][starty] = true;
            System.out.println(mindis);
            System.out.println("minx: " + minx + " miny: " + miny);
```

Comment: Without code, it is difficult to say for certain, but don't `JPanel` objects have a `.setVisible()`?

Comment: Since you are drawing that text onto the canvas directly, why don't you just replace `g.drawString("Solving...", ...)` with `g.drawString("Solved", ...)` based on whether it is still running or not?

Comment: Please post code as text using the code tool.

Comment: simple don't draw it if you don't want it to be displayed? @Thomas gave a possible solution - I would rather either prepare the graphic somewhere else(and just apply the prepared image), put a dispatch in the method or most probably use a ready to use control(a lable) for the text. But thats up to you.

Comment: You do not remove. You `repaint()` and draw only what you want on the screen.